# How to combine multiple row values in Oracle SQL in a single table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been having trouble combining multiple row values into a single column for each semester.

The table (GENERALEDPATHWAY) has these columns:

*STUDENTID

*SEMESTER

*CLASS

*CLASS_COMBINATION (all values currently null)

*YEAR

*CLASS_GRADE

*ENTRYPOINT

*DEGREE

*CLASS_DISTRIBUTION

*DEGREE

*GRADUATED_IN

I'm only currently worried about the STUDENTID, SEMESTER, CLASS, and Class_Combination. Every student has a unique ID and may have a different combination of classes each semester. Instead of having a separate row for every class every semester, I want to put the class values into the CLASS_COMBINATION column. EX: instead of having 5 rows for 5 classes taken in a single semester, I just want 1 row for that semester with all classes listed alphabetically separated by commas in the CLASS_COMBINATION column.

The difficulty I'm having is that all of the information is in a single table and needs to work in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried, what result did you expect, and what result did you get? Also it's helpful if you can post sample data for the table you are selecting from.

Comment: check LISTAGG (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
Select studentid, semester, class,
Listagg(class) within group (order by class) as CLASS_COMBINATION
From GENERALEDPATHWAY
Group by studentid, semester, class;
```

If you want to update the table. Then use it in `update` or `merge` query to update each recoed and then remove the duplicate rows.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is an aggregation query, with one row per student and semester.

You do not need a separate *table* for this.  My recommendation is either a simple query or a view.

Your data structure describes `STUDENTID` as the primary key.  However, you specify that you have multiple rows for a `STUDENTID`, so something is wrong -- either your explanation or the data model.  From what you describe, you want:

```
select STUDENTID, semester,
       listagg(class ', ') within group (order by class) as classes
from GENERALEDPATHWAY
group by STUDENTID, semester;
```